# Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Client, Version ERROR

Tags: asp.net, .net, dll, dynamics-crm-2011, .net-assembly

I'm creating an ASP web app that will connect to CRM.
but I got error every time I run my application: 
ERROR
 Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Client

Using the Microsoft.Xrm.Client.dll Version: 5.0.9690.2165  as reference give us an error :

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Client, Version=5.0.9689.2166, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

But when we replace the dll with  Microsoft.Xrm.Client.dll Version: 5.0.9689.2166 as reference give us an error:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Client, Version=5.0.9690.2165, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

And I cant add both version as my Reference.
I'm confused what version on of the Microsoft.Xrm.Client.dll Version to use to debug this Error.

Comment: Which CRM are you using, CRM Online ? CRM On-Premise ?

Comment: I tried both Online and On-Premise. But same result.

Comment: use the nuget package or download the latest sdk and use also all the other libraries from it

Comment: @Guido

can you please give me a link to download to make sure were having same reference. Thanks sir.

Comment: crm 2011 sdk http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=24004, you can try also to use the 2013 version http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=40321

Answer (score 0):

Please let us know if you were able to resolve this, if so what was the reason.

In my case, i had a plugin which was used to create users in MSCRM.

I had two different organizations, **Org A** and **Org B.**

1. As per functionality it was needed that whenever a new user is created in Org A same should be created in Org B
2. So we registered the plugin on Org A
3. As the organization B was created using database restore the **same plugin was also registered in org B**
4. So, on Creation of user in Org A, plugin of **Org A** was triggered, which tried to create User in **Org B**
5. At the same time as the same plugin was available in Org B it was also triggered.
6. As per my understanding **Org B** also tried to load the assembly Microsoft.Xrm.Client.dll which was currently being used by plugin of **Org A**.

So we were getting the error

`Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Xrm.Client, Version=5.0.9689.2166, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)`

Hope this will help somebody!